# Short answer deleted, not sure why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Yesterday I provided a short answer to a question, and it has been deleted as if it was a comment:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/270394/40631

I don't think it was a comment, somebody asked what the name of a pattern is and I told them what name I was taught to use for that pattern.

I'm not sure how to rewrite my answer so that it wouldn't be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was deleted by a moderator because it did not meet the quality standards we have for answers on this site.  Short one sentence answers really fail to capture a full explanation needed, even if the OP is asking a painfully simple question.

Here is a link with some helpful information on how to write better answers.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for the link but I've been partaking in stack exchange twice as long as you and am very familiar with how to answer questions. Are you seriously saying I should have padded my answer out with a bunch of extra fluff just to make it longer? Where does it say that on the how to answer page? "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better". My answer was brief but it also fully explains the point I was trying to get across. Some questions have very simple answers. Again, I asked how I should have written my answer differently to avoid being deleted. An advice is appreciated.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert your on-site rep (a bit over 100 without association bonus) is about 200 times less than that of the answerer. This suggests that their understanding of site quality norms may be more solid. FWIW many other SE sites have low tolerance about one-liner notes, eg Workplace, Skeptics, Code Golf, Parenting...

Comment: So basically it's better not to have answers than to have short answers? OK... I guess we can agree to disagree.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: The main problem with your answer is that you didn't try to explain *why* the name you use is the best/correct name. Without that, it is just another opinion equally valuable as the dozens other possible "I call it X" answers.